# How to add search in table view in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I want to add search in dynamic table view using NSMutableArray, actually I'm using json to add products in table so I need NSMutableArray

*First I assign the values as it*

```
var filteredItems = [String]()
var searchController:UISearchController!
var products:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

I'm using moltin API and using NSArray as it is..

```
        if let newProducts:NSArray = response?["result"] as? NSArray {
            self.products.addObjects(from: newProducts as [AnyObject])

        }


        let responseDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: response!)

        if let newOffset:NSNumber = responseDictionary.value(forKeyPath: "pagination.offsets.next") as? NSNumber {
            self.paginationOffset = newOffset.intValue
```

I'm also using this for cell

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as! ProductsListTableViewCell

    let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row



let product:NSDictionary = products.object(at: row) as! NSDictionary

    cell.configureWithProduct(product)

    return cell
```

In view did load I'm using correct method for search bar on navigation bar.

I'm using this function for filtering result, but it couldn't work and give an error:

> can not convert value to type (_) -> _ to accepted argument type 'NSPredict'

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredItems.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    // filter
    filteredItems = products.filter{
        item in

        item.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())
    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

But when I'm using simple array of items it works very well for me. How I can use it in *NSMutableArray*?

Comment: What does your `products` contain? Only `String`(`NSString`)?

Comment: Actually I'm using moltin API as DB  and using NSArray

Comment: I do not know _moltin API_, so it cannot be any clue about _What does your products contain_.

Comment: ` 
            if   let   newProducts:NSArray = response?["result"] as? NSArray {
                self.products.addObjects(from: newProducts as [AnyObject])
  
            }

Comment: How can I send you image of my code so that you can understand my problem ??

Comment: You know you can edit your question.

Comment: @OOPer plz check it now..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *using json* does not mean you *need NSMutableArray*.

I would re-write your code as:

(Assuming `response` is `NSDictionary?` and response["result"] is an array of string. If this assumption does not match your case, you may need to add some more info about what response["result"] contains.)

```
var products: [String] = []
```

and:

```
    if let newProducts = response?["result"] as? [String] {
        self.products.append(contentsOf: newProducts)
    }
```

With this change, your `filteredItems = ...` should work without any modifications.

---

If you insist on using `NSMutableArray`, you may need to write something like this:

```
    filteredItems = (products as NSArray as! [String]).filter {
        item in

        item.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())
    }
```

Or this:

```
    filteredItems = products.filter {
        item in

        (item as! String).lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())
    }.map{$0 as! String}
```

---

If those codes above does not solve your issue, you may need to edit your question to provide some more info.

Comment: I'm understanding your answer but there is something different in my case I update my question with more details please check it now...

Comment: @Kamboh, seems your `products` is not an array of simple strings, then in your code, `item` becomes a dictionary and there's no method `lowercased` in `NSDictionary` or Swift Dictionary. Back to the first point, what does your `products` actually contain?